Handling windows dialog box to select a folder with Selenium on Electron app
I'm currently automating an Electron app using Selenium with C#. So far most things are doable similar to browser automation however I ran into a bit of an issue.
We have a button which opens a windows dialog to select a folder that reads the files within. The folder path will then be displayed a field beside the select folder button. When performed manually the only way to select the folder is to use the windows browser.
This is modified snippt of the html


<div class="FormControl-root">
   <div class="Box-root">
      <div class="Box-root">
         <button class="ButtonBase-root"
            tabindex="0" type="button" style="white-space: nowrap;">Choose Folder
         <span class="Touch-root"></span></button>
      </div>
      <div class="Box-root">
         <div class="FormControl-root ">
            <label class="FormLabel-root"
               data-shrink="true" for=":r10:" id="r-label">Folder path</label>
            <div class="InputBase-root" style="pointer-events: none;">
               <input aria-invalid="false" id="r-input" type="text" class="InputBase" value="Select Folder">
               <fieldset
                  aria-hidden="true" class="OutlinedInput">
                  <legend class="css-1"><span>Folder path</span></legend>
               </fieldset>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>



I have tried the following:
I use SendKeys with the folder path as the value to the button element. Which doesn't do anything except that it opens the windows dialog to select the folder.
public void SupplyFolderPath(string path)
{
        var selectFolderButton = _driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[@class='ButtonBase-root']"));
        selectFolderButton.SendKeys(path);
}

Used SendKeys for input field element and using path to the folder as the value. This didn't do anything except it place a cursor in the field.
public void SupplyFolderPath(string path)
{
        var folderField = _driver.FindElement(By.Id("r-input"));
        folderField.SendKeys(path);
}

I've used Javascript executor to set the value of the input element to that of the file path. This did not work at all.
public void SupplyFolderPath(string path)
{
        var folderField = _driver.FindElement(By.Id("r-input"));
        var je = (IJavaScriptExecutor)_driver;
        je.ExecuteScript($"arguments[0].value='{path}';", folderField);
}

I then attempted to use Javascript executor to set the value of the attribute type for the button element to file first and then use SendKeys with the folder path as the value. This also did not work and just opens the dialog box like in the first attempt mentioned above.
 public void SupplyFolderPath(string path)
 {
        var selectFolderButton = _driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[@class='ButtonBase-root']"));
        var je = (IJavaScriptExecutor)_driver;
        je.ExecuteScript($"arguments[0].setAttribute('type', 'file')", selectFolderButton);
 }

This issue might not specifically be Electron app. I wonder if anyone have any suggestions or advice as I'm out of ideas. Or do I have to start looking at other tools which I'm trying to avoid?

sending path using send keys will only work for <input type="file" element... sounds like the browse is triggered outside of browser context.  As far as I know the browser's built-in file selection cannot select folders, but only a single or multiple files.  The value of the <input type="text" is updated with the file path(s).  Might not be able to handle this without robot-like framework or building test into the hooked method.

Thank you. If I'm understanding your comment correctly, I take it the only way is to start looking other tools to handle the pop up. The last part regarding building test into the hooked method. Do you mean by on source code level?

yes at source code level... you'd want to send the folder path into the browse dialog directly.  It might also be possible to automate browse dialogs from appium/winium?

I tried H.InputSimulator for .NET and I was able to interact with the folder explorer. I click on the open folder button and using input simulator I input the folder path and then simulate TAB and RETURN to enter and close the dialog. The only thing now is when clicking on the open folder button to open the window explorer. I have to put the click action within a try and catch block to catch WebDriver Exception. Then I can execute the input simulator commands.

you should include your code as an answer here.  (you are allowed to answer your own questions)  I'm sure it'll help many others.
